# Installing Tensorflow problem : pip doesn't upgraded

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

> (tensorflow) C:\Users>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
>   Collecting pip
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   twisted 18.7.0 requires PyHamcrest>=1.9.0, which is not installed.
>   Installing collected packages: pip
>     Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
>       Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] 액세스가 거부되었습니다: 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

**I installed Anaconda3.7 and now I'm trying to install the tensorflow, but it seems the version of pip is problem. 
So I typed 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command several times but it didn't work at all. Is there a way to install it?**

Comment: have you read the error you provide? have you tried the solution they propose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. You messed Anaconda up with your pip install.

I had to reset my machine to factory settings, as reinstalling Anaconda gave me some conflict errors.

Once I reset my machine the command I typed was:

conda install tensorflow

you might also look into keras and theano.

Good luck buddy. You are not the only one to have done this. Anaconda is tricky like that.